# The only thing I understood was espresso

Tags: riddle, word, language

> Cogito ergo sum,
>   Om mani padme hum.
>   Ordem e progresso,
>   Cognac e espresso.
>
> One of the speech,
>   One of the mouth,
>   One of the tongue,
>   One into the mouth.

Looking for four words of four letters each.

Hint:

> What language is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The four words are:

> One of the speech — **LISP**
>   One of the mouth — **LIPS**
>   One of the tongue — **SLIP**
>   One into the mouth — **PILS**

They are ...

> ... anagrams of the first letters of the languages used in the poem:
>
>  Cogito ergo sum — **L**atin
>  Om mani padme hum — **S**anskrit
>  Ordem e progresso — **P**ortuguese
>  Cognac ed espresso — **I**talian

Answer (score 3):

I did some look ups and this is my answer

Cogito ergo sum

> = "I think, therefore I am" ->  One of the speech: **Poem** (Philisophy)

Om mani padme hum.

> = tibetian mantra  -> One of the mouth: I have to guess this one; **Soul**? (Religion)

Ordem e progresso,

> = the flag of brasil -> One of the tongue: I have to guess another one; **Flag**

Cognac e espresso.

> = a baverage  -> One into the mouth: **Shot** (You get a shot of espresso)

Comment: This fits pretty well, although the third line isn't really rot13[hfrq va na nagurz]. Note that I've since edited the question to limit the answers to 4-letter words.

Comment: I have corrected my answer. Is this going into the right direction?

Comment: I have added a hint :)

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the riddle is:

> Written in 4 different languages

And means:

> **Latin** - I think therefore I am
>  **Hindi** - Do you believe me?
>  **Portugeuse** - Order and Progress
>  **Italian** - Cognac and espresso

The second part of the riddle:

> Uses English to refer to each of the previous lines. "*One into the mouth*" must be the Caffè corretto (cognac and espresso). "*I think therefore I am*" is part of Descartes *speech*.

I presume the four words you are looking for are:

> The four languages of Latin, Hindi, Portugeuse and Italian?

Comment: Good start! Note that I've since edited the question to limit the answers to 4-letter words.

Comment: The second one is in rot 13(Fnafxevg)